# How to scroll up automatically when button is clicked and error comes in long form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a long form which is scrollable as its saves in when button is clicked, but how to scroll up if error comes?

I have made a form. Now it has 40 points to be listed. There are some dropdowns, some textboxes and some checkboxes. I have also made mandatory fields.
But now the button is in bottom. So I need to give functionality that if the user click the button and validation happens  it shows some error message and it automatically scrolls up.

I don't know how would it be possible. I am working on ASP.NET website using bootstrap design.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from your tags that you can use JS, so here's a vanilla solution:

```
// Trigger the error
if (error) {
    // Get the element by its id
    var errorElement = document.getElementById("errorElementId");
    // Scroll to it
    window.scrollTo(0, errorElement.offsetTop);
}
```

That's also assuming your form isn't inside an element with `overflow: scroll` on it. In that case, you'll need to make sure the parent has `position: relative` and use this:

```
// Trigger the error
if (error) {
    // Get the element 
    var errorElement = document.getElementById("errorElementId");
    // Get the parent element
    var parentElement = document.getElementById("parentElementId");
    // Scroll to it
    parentElement.scrollTop = errorElement.offsetTop;
}
```